# Drawing box-plot only white max and min in python

Tags: python, plot, box

I would like to draw box-plot for below data set but I don't need tails . I need a tip whit  max and min on edges Only like in the picture  .

Please help.

Thank you.

I try using libre office Excel but didn't work

Comment: You forgot to include the dataset and a picture

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.